# Showing that $P$ is unique

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, cubics

Suppose, we have the data points $f_a,f_b$ as well as $f_a',f_b'$. We have a cubic spline $P(x)=c(x-a)^3+d(x-a)^2+e(x-a)+f$ in $[a,b]$ where:$$P(a)=f_a, \, P(b)=f_b,\, P'(a)=f_a' \, \text{ und } P'(b)=f_b'$$

I want to show that this setting will give a unique polynomial.

**My attempt**

We have $P'(x)=3c(x-a)^2+2d(x-a)+e$ and thus:$$ \begin{cases}P(a)=f=f_a \\ P(b)=c(b-a)^3+d(b-a)^2+e(b-a)+f_a=f_b \\ P'(a)=e=f_a' \\ P'(b)=3c(b-a)^2+2d(b-a)+f_a'=f_b'\end{cases}$$

How do I know that this will yield a unique $P$? How can I solve this system of equations?

**Important note** We have $b>a$.

Comment: Why do you call this a spline ? It is a Bézier curve.

Comment: You have a linear system of 4 equations with 4 unknows. Is its  determinant non zero ?

Comment: You're right, Jean Marie.

Comment: Aren't there more unknowns? Like $a,b,c,d,e,f$?

Comment: $a,b$ aren't unknowns. Only $c,d,e,f$ are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) First step : identifying your expression

$$P(x)=c(x-a)^3+d(x-a)^2+e(x-a)+f$$

with (exact) Taylor expansion of $P$ in the vicinity of $a$:

$$P(x)=P(a)+P'(a)(x-a)+\frac12 P''(a)(x-a)^2+ \frac16 P'''(a)(x-a)^3$$

already gives two coefficients :

- 1. $P(a)=f=f_a$ (you had found it)
- 2. $P'(a)=f'_a=e$.

B) Second step : Therefore, it remains to find the two unknowns $c,d$ in expression :

$$P(x)=c(x-a)^3+d(x-a)^2+f'_a(x-a)+f_a$$

taking account of

- a) $P(b)=f_b \ \iff \ c(b-a)^3+d(b-a)^2+f'_a(b-a)+f_a=f_b$
- b) $P'(b)=f'_b \ \iff \ 3c(b-a)^2+2d(b-a)+f'_a=f'_b$

Therefore, we have a linear system of 2 equations with 2 unknowns $c,d$:

$$\begin{cases}c(b-a)^3+d(b-a)^2&=&f_b-f_a-f'_a(b-a)\\3c(b-a)^2+2d(b-a)&=&f'_b-f'_a\end{cases}$$

Said otherwise :

$$\begin{cases}c(b-a)+d&=&\frac{f_b-f_a-f'_a(b-a)}{(b-a)^2}\\3c(b-a)+2d&=&\frac{f'_b-f'_a}{(b-a)}\end{cases}$$

Can you take it from here ?

Comment: Any comment ?...

Comment: I got it, thanks.